# A LDAP recipient not being resolved correctly when calling Recipient.Resolve

Tags: c#, outlook, ldap, outlook-addin, mapi

I am developing an outlook Addin c# using outlook object model. My Addin code needs to resolve the recipient in order to act on it based on its resolved type (AddressEntryUserType).

I use the Recipient.Resolve() method which is working good enough. However, the problem is that when sending a message while entering an address in the "To" field, the email (which I know for a fact that it should be an LDAP entry) does not resolve to an LDAP entry. Instead, it is resolved to be an SMTP address entry. I have no way to know in the code that this is actually an LDAP entry.

Note: when pressing the "To" button and using the address book to select the LDAP entry. the Recipient resolves correctly.

What should I do in this case? is there a way to overcome this issue? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying you expect the address type to be "LDAP" rather than "SMTP"? Are you not sending through an SMTP or Exchange transport? How would they know how to handle that address type?

Comment: Yes for the first question. The ldap server containing the entry is configured as an address book. I do not understand your second question. Can you elaborate more.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "does not resolve to an LDAP entry"? You are passing just a name or an SMTP address? In the latter case it can get resolved to a one-off SMTP entry.

Comment: I mean instead of being resolved to an AddressEntry of type olLdapAddressEntry, it is being resolved to olSmtpAddressEntry.

Comment: Why is it a problem? Do you get an error when the message is sent?

Comment: No there is no problem, but I need to know if the recipient source is in one of the LDAP sources defined in the address book or not, based on that I do some actions as part of the application logic I am doing.

Comment: So are you passing in an SMTP address or a display name to resolve?

Comment: yes, the SMTP address is one of the address entries in an LDAP address book. I thought it should resolve to that. the same way an SMTP address from an exchange based domain resolves to an exchange entry. anyway, it looks like this is one of the weird behaviours of outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Based on the comments for the original question) - If you want to resolve a name against a particular AB container, you can either uses Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi only) and call [IABContainer.ResolveNames](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms629706%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). If that fails, you can try to use [PR_ANR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/address-book-restrictions) restriction against that container's contents table.

If Extended MAPI is not an option, you can use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) and its [RDOAddressList](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAddressList.htm).`ResolveName` method. It will use the two approaches outlined above and is accessible from any language.

Comment: you are saying if I use Redemption, I don't need to use OOM recipient.resolve() method at all? i can see the example in the documentation. the result of RDOAddressList.ResolveName is an AddressEntry. How to assign this AddressEntry to a Recipient in a message. in OOM, I see Recipient.AddressEntry as read/write, while in Redemption it is not.

Comment: I don't think you'd be able to assign it back, but I thought you are just checking whether the recipient comes from an LDAP address book? The message would still go out to its intended recipient since the address is good regardless.